# How do I get the path of a filename when only filename is known?

Tags: c#

Say I have a compiled `C#` program (let's call it `example2.exe`) in a directory in system `$PATH`, so I can call it from any folder from Windows. In command line I go into `c:\apps` and run `example2.exe` with an existing file as an argument, for example: `example2.exe file.txt`. Is it possible to get the full path of `file.txt`?

Another option could be `..\file.txt`, which wouldn't point to a file in a current dictionary.

Comment: How do you know `"file.txt"` string represents a file name to the compiled program `"example2"`?

Comment: The user would typically mean c:\apps\file.txt.  The value returned by Path.GetFullPath() if Environment.CurrentDirectory is set correctly.  It should be.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Could you rephrase your question, please? I'm not sure what you had in mind.

Comment: @menteith `example2.exe` is a compiled program. You need to make an assumption about what it does with the string `"file.txt"` which is passed to it as the argument. If you have no access to the source code of the program, you must either make assumptions about the initial directory for the search for `"file.txt"`, or let the program run in a way that lets you detect all files that it opens. An assumption of the current directory as the starting point could be right, but the program may literally do anything, e.g. prepend `"c:\temp\"` to `"..\file.txt"`, etc.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight When you call "del myfile.txt" on command line, which file would you expect getting deleted? The one relative to the current directory or relative to something hidden coded inside the del command?

Comment: @SirRufo You are talking about `del` command, for which the semantics is well specified. OP, on the other hand, talks about a compiled program called `example2.exe`, which can do whatever the heck it wants to do. Interpreting it as "it treats the string precisely the way that `del` command does" is one possible assumption.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I failed to mention that I'm creating an application and this assumption is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Directory.GetCurrentDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx) is what you are looking for.

```
var fileName = "file.txt"; //comes from args obviously
var fullPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), fileName);
```

Comment: How do you know that the compiled program reads from its current directory? For all we know, it could be reading from `c:\temp\file.txt`, because interpretation of the file name is entirely up to the running program.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a current dictionary since I  could give as an argument `..\file.txt`.

Comment: I would treat a relative filename always relative to the current directory. Thats what 99% of all applications will do.

Comment: @menteith When current directory is c:\temp\foo and the argument is ..\file.txt then combined you get c:\temp\foo\..\file.txt which is exactly the same as c:\temp\file.txt

Comment: @SirRufo Thanks for you explaination. Now this seems to be clearer to me.

Comment: @menteith You should use https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.path.getfullpath(v=vs.110).aspx which internally does exactly the same as the code above, but you can be sure to treat the filename as the current platform will do. But remeber to get the full path as soon as possible, otherwise you maybe will get a different filename once you change the current dir without knowing (some dialogs may change the current directory)